# Do we use rms values or peak value for calculating power of a transformer?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, power

Do we use rms values or peak value for calculating power of a transformer?

Comment: Are you asking for real power or apparent poer of a transformer?

Comment: Which do you use for a resistor? Do you understand *why* you make that choice for a resistor?

Comment: In signal processing, RMS _is_ power...wait.. hold the R.

Answer (score 1):

Peak level might mean "the amount of power that caused transformer failure."

Rms (root mean square) might mean "typical continuous running load power".